# Grails: Dynamically call another action

Tags: grails, grails-controller

Is it possible to call another controller-action with the name of the controller-action being passed as a parameter. Something like this:

View:

```
<g:createLink controller="book" action="list"
params="[id: '1', onCompleteController='nextCon', onCompleteAction='nextAct']"/>
```

Controller (Book):

```
def list = {
   ... //Do something like save book

   **execute onCompleteController/onCompleteAction**

   return render(text: [success:true] as JSON))

}
```

Answer (score 5):

you can do that by using forward or redirect (which ever fits in your case).

Some thing like

```
redirect(controller:onCompleteController, action: onCompleteAction, model:[])

forward(controller:onCompleteController, action: onCompleteAction, params:[])
```

Comment: The difference being that `redirect` returns a 3xx response to the user agent which must make another request to the new action VS. `forward` which does the redirect server-side and does not change the user agent's URL.